# Input redirection the same as output redirection

Tags: unix, io-redirection

When I run the command:

> cat < foo > foo

With **foo** is an atribary file, I thought **foo** will remain the same since we make **foo** the input and output of **cat** command. But it turned out that this command erase **foo**. Otherwise, if I redirect the input to **bar** by

> cat < foo > bar

Then I got **bar** is the copy of **foo**. I can't figure it out why? What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting output to a file is done by the shell that runs your commands and it causes the file's content to be completely erased, which is exactly what you see with the first command. The second command creates a new file `bar` (or overwrites it).

Shell doesn't know or care what `cat` does. All it knows is that it should run `cat` and make it read it's input from one file and redirect to another.

If you want to *replace* file `foo` contents with the output of the command, most portable way is using a temporary file. Below is a skeleton for it:

```
tmpfile=.....  # temporary name - see mktemp for portable secure ways to create it!
cat < foo > $tmpfile
mv $tmpfile foo
```